# Android contact app layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-contacts

Wich is the best aproach here? I have a list of phones, another one for emails, and another one for names, all of them is in a database and I need to achieve the following result:

[image]

It has to be exactly like that image, I'm not asking anyone to right te code for me, I just need to know what is the best way to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear layout may be a good starting point.